# Finding a row with the highest frequency

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Hr  Loc Freq    
0   79  5546

0   132 5456

0   48  4359

0   249 4089

0   230 3485
... ... ...
23  227 1
23  240 1
23  250 1
23  251 1
23  258 1
```

It contains about 5000 rows with the "Hr" column as index. I want to group the dataframe by Hr and find the "Loc" that has the highest (Freq)Frequency value.

I have done this:

`location.groupby(['Hour']).Frequency.max()`

which created a new Series:

```
Hr
0      5546
1      5394
2      3745
3      2500
4      1232
5      2387
6      5690
7      6164
8      7354
9      8346
10     8846
11     9974
12    10718
13    11031
14    12306
15    12159
16    11482
17    11876
18    12079
19    11332
20    10285
21    10611
22    11031
23    10181
```

that has the highest Frequency values, but it doesn't have the corresponding "Loc" value that matches it. How do I create or include that?

What I want is something like this:

```
Hr Loc Freq
0  79  5546
... ... ...
23 59  10181
```

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), post the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). Also, please provide a [mre], meaning complete example data and desired output. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips, like how to write a good title.

Comment: Duplicate: [Get the row(s) which have the max value in groups using groupby](/q/15705630/4518341)

Comment: (Sorry, I would have posted that first, but I forgot it existed.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try leverage [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

> Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.

```py
result = df.loc[df.groupby(['Hr']).Freq.idxmax()]
```

Note that as quote says - in case of duplicate maximums the first row will be returned.